Connect a 3-pin 5V DC fan to a Grove - 16 Channel PWM Driver
I wish to connect a 3-pin 5V DC fan like Arctic f9  to a Grove - 16 Channel PWM Driver (PCA9685)
Does the fan cable match the connector. What is the correct seeeduino connector type shown in

Thanks a lot

That fan cannot be controlled via PWM. The third pin is the sense output, where you can measure the actual speed of the fan. It is NOT a PWM input. You can see this in the pin diagram in the spec sheet.
To control the speed of the fan you need to vary the voltage, that you power the fan with, between 4V and 12V. (See the part "Controlling the fan" -> "In a DIY project" in the manual) When you find a fitting MOSFET or transistor you could use it in its linear range so build a simple amplifiern which could be controlled with a PWM signal filtered through a low pass filter (using a capacitor and a resistor) to get an analog voltage from PWM.
Or - and this would be simpler - just buy a fan, that actually can be controlled via PWM. The 4-pin variants should work for that, but always check in the spec sheet and the manual beforehand.
The connector shown in the diagram from seeeduino is a simple female dupont connector, so nothing specific to seeeduino.

Thanks a lot, it is a big help. so can I connected the F9 to one of the PWM Channel and treat it like a normal fan running at constant speed? Furthermore, how do I deal with the connections to the board with F9 PWM https://www.arctic.de/en/F9-PWM/ACFAN00213A

You can only connect the 4-pin variant to the PWM directly. That is important. For the 3-pin variant you would need additional electronics. And for the connector: You need to change the pin order of the fans connector to match the output of the seeeduino board. Sometimes the pins can be pulled out of the dupont connector (when pulling on a small tap) and put back together in the needed order (depends on how arctic does its connectors). Or you would need to cut off the original connector and put on your own dupont connector with the correct order

Thanks for the question, answers and discussion.
What about using Noctua NF-A14 5V
https://noctua.at/en/nf-a14-5v and this driver.
I can not find any information about its 3-pin cable and I do not know if it fits the dupont  connecters . BTW I have  do not need the PWM. Thanks

@jane please post your own question ... the comment section of an answer is not the place for it

The connector shown in the image from Seeedstudio is a JST-PH 4-pin connector, which is typical for Grove modules. It won’t directly match the fan's 3-pin connector, so you’ll need a custom solution to connect them.
